# Why do tools like yacc and ANTLR generate source code?

Tags: antlr, yacc, auto-generate

These tools basically input a grammar and output code which processes a series of tokens into something more useful, like a syntax tree. But could these tools be written in the form of a library instead? What is the reason for generating source code as output? Is there a performance gain? Is it more flexible for the end user? Easier to implement for the authors of yacc and ANTLR?

Sorry if the question is too vague, I'm just curious about the historical reasons behind the decisions the authors made, and what purpose auto-generated code has in today's environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a big performance advantage achieved by the parser generator working out the interactions of the grammar rules with respect to one another, and compiling the result to code.

One could build interpreters that simply accepted grammars and did the parsing; there are parser types ([Earley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser)) that would actually be relatively good at that, and one could compute the grammar interactions at runtime (Earley parsers kind of do this anyway) rather than offline and then execute the parsing algorithm.

But you would pay a parsing performance penalty of 10 to 100x slowdown, and probably a big storage demand.

If you are parsing using only very small grammars, or you are parsing only very small documents, this might not matter.  But the grammars that many parser generators get applied too end up being fairly big (people keep wanting to add things to what you can say in a language), and they often end up processing pretty big documents.  So performance now matters, and viola, people build code-generating parser generators.

Once you have a tool, it is often easier to use even in simple cases.  So now that you *have* parser generators, you can even apply them to little grammars or to parsing little documents.

EDIT: Addendum.  The *historical* reason is probably driven by space and time demands.  Earlier systems had not a lot of room (32Kb in 1975), didn't run very fast (1 MIPS same time frame), and people had big source files already.   Parser generators tended to help with this set of problems; interpreted grammars would have had intolerably bad performance.

Answer (score 3):

[Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter) gave you one set of reasons for not handling the grammar parsing at runtime.

There is another reason too.  Associated with each rule in the grammar is the appropriate action.  The action is normally a fragment of a separate language (for example, C or C++).  All actions in a grammar interpreted at runtime would have to be mappable to something appropriate in the program.  In general, that's a losing proposition.  The fragments can do all sorts of things, referencing parts of the stack (`$$`, `$1`, etc) and invoking actions (`YYACCEPT`, etc).  Designing the runtime system so that it could be reliably used with such fragments would be tough.  You'd like be into creating source code and compiling that into a DSO (dynamic shared object) or DLL (dynamic link library) and loading it.  That requires a compiler on the customer's machine, where the customer may have deliberately designed their production system to be compiler-free.

Comment: If you are willing to "interpret" the grammar rules, you are probably willing to interpret the procedural attachments to them, too. So one doesn't necessarily have to "compile" that code.

Comment: "Compile" as in 'run C compiler'?  Maybe not, but the flexibility of the actions that people exploit in real-world grammars makes interpreting them extremely difficult to manage unless the fragments are written in an interpretable language.  It would be extremely difficult for the 'grammar system' to make unconstrained use of the raw power of the actions that is exposed to, and exploited by, the grammars I normally see.  There'd also be limits on the data structures that could be handled, assuming that the whole program isn't interpreted.  It may be doable; it is anything but trivial to do!

Comment: Yep, its a bunch of work to replace the effort of the compiler *and* the parser generator.  Which is why people tend not to do that :-} FWIW, I think the "actions" in many such rules is artificially complex and could be simplified considerably.  If you want to write arbitrary programs in such actions, you'll need arbitrarily complex interpreters to process it.   By limiting what you can say, it can get a lot easier to build the interpreter.  (We build tools that automatically form trees; all that goes in the action is code to convert the text into a binary equivalent value, if any).

Comment: ... anyway +1 for another answer.

Comment: Thanks for the vote.  I agree that the action code in grammars is often less than stellar and should usually be simpler than it is.